# How to sort list of classes in java

Tags: java

How can I sort ascending/descending this list of classes by id in Java?

```
[Complaints{id=1, state='inregistrata'}, Complaints{id=3, state='solutionata'}, Complaints{id=2, state='solutionata'}]
```

Comment: What have you tried sofar? What didn't work or where are you stuck? Already tried `List.sort()` ? Can you share your `Complaints` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using Java's `Comparable` interface.

The `Comparable` interface is used to make instances comparable with each other. It works by implementing the interface's `compareTo()` method. The way it works is simple;

Let's say we have two objects; `o1` and `o2`. `compareTo()` returns an integer that carries information about the comparison of the two instances.

- If `o1` > `o2`, then `compareTo()` should return an integer **>0**.
- If `o1` < `o2`, then `compareTo()` should return an integer **<0**.
- Finally, ff `o1` == `o2`, then `compareTo()` should return exactly **0**.

You can base the comparison on whichever attribute you like. An implementation that might work for you follows;

First, in your `Complaint` class implement the `Comparable` interface like this;

```
public class Complaint implements Comparable<Complaint> {
   ...
}
```

Then, implement `compareTo()` like this;

```
public class Complaint implements Comparable<Complaint> {
    private int id;
    private String state;

    //... other code ...

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Complaint c) {
        if (this.id == c.getId()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.id > c.getId()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you do the above, you can now use Java's `Collections.sort()` method to sort your complaint instances.

```
List complaints = new ArrayList<Complaint>();
complaints.add(new Complaint(2, "solutionata"));
complaints.add(new Complaint(1, "inregistrata"));
complaints.add(new Complaint(3, "solutionata"));

Collections.sort(complaints); // sort in ascending order 
Collections.reverse(complaints); // sort in descending order
```

Do not forget to import Collections:

`import java.util.Collections;`